# Cannot Install Laravel 5 on CentOS 7

Tags: php, laravel, centos, laravel-5, laravel-blade

> I tried to install a fresh laravel project on CentOS 7 running
>   Apache/PHP 5.6/MariaDB.

on `/var/www` :

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel devil
chmod -R 777 devil/storage
chmod -R 777 devil/vendor
```

> When I tried to access it from browser, it seems the blade extension
>   is not working. It keep showing blank page without any error.

I checked the HTTP response showing 500 (Internal server error) on my chrome web developer extension.

The app only work if I don't use blade templating at all (not use .blade.php extension and the blade syntax).

Below is the folder structure

```
drwxr-xr-x. 10 adzar adzar   4096 Mar 25 04:06 app
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 adzar adzar   1635 Mar 25 04:06 artisan
drwxr-xr-x.  2 adzar adzar     39 Mar 25 04:06 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar    788 Mar 25 04:06 composer.json
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar 100509 Mar 25 04:06 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x.  2 adzar adzar   4096 Mar 25 04:06 config
drwxr-xr-x.  4 adzar adzar     52 Mar 25 04:06 database
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar    503 Mar 25 04:06 gulpfile.js
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar     98 Mar 25 04:06 package.json
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar     87 Mar 25 04:06 phpspec.yml
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar    777 Mar 25 04:06 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x.  4 adzar adzar     95 Mar 25 04:06 public
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar   1724 Mar 25 04:06 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x.  5 adzar adzar     42 Mar 25 04:06 resources
-rw-r--r--.  1 adzar adzar    560 Mar 25 04:06 server.php
drwxrwxrwx.  5 adzar adzar     60 Mar 25 04:06 storage
drwxr-xr-x.  2 adzar adzar     47 Mar 25 04:06 tests
drwxrwxrwx. 26 adzar adzar   4096 Apr  8 18:31 vendor
```

The `.env file` (unchanged)

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=EOvUHTpMtavKDMx1GdkREtbves8PVEUb

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
```

I use IP address `(100.255.XXX.XXX)` to access my app using apache virtual host. Below is my `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`.

```
...

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName 100.255.XXX.XXX

...

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 100.255.XXX.XXX
        DocumentRoot /var/www/devil/public

        <Directory /var/www/devil>
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Any error messages in response body?
Check also apache logs

Comment: No message in response body. Here is log from apache http://pastebin.com/eh3MC1D7. It said permission denied at `storage` folder, however I already set the permission to 777.

Comment: Did you set the permission for all sub folders as well?

Comment: I have a very similar infrastructure, I fixed it doing `chmod 777` to  index.php file

Answer (score 0):

I know, that its dirty-solution but try to chmod 0777 on all application files with recurrency (to chmod also all subdirectories and files).

PHP error from apache log i really easy to understand (it just says: I don't have permission to log files)

I think, that you also have disabled error reporting and thats why you can't see errors in response body

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

After hours of trying I finally able to fix the problem by disabling SELinux.

```
setenforce 0
```

However, I still have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel not support SELinux so you need to disable and 2 directories permissions should be 775 storage and bootstrap/cache.

```
find storage -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
chmod 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Change SELinux to disable

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

Enjoy Laravel5.x on CentOS7

Answer (score 0):

i dont think its necessary to chmod on vendor directory

you can use this config

chmod 755 -R /var/www/html
chmod -R o+w /var/www/html/storage

Also install mysql-server . i got error on mariadb

there is a detailed guide you can follow [laravel 5 on centos 7.2](http://sparkledge.com/install-laravel-5-0-lamp-phpmyadmin-on-centos-7-2/)

Answer (score 0):

Of course Laravel can work with Security Enhanced Linux enabled, you just need to set it up right.

Laravel "compiles" the blade templates to ./storage/framework/views/*.php and the webuser needs write rights into that directory, of course, with SELinux enabled, this means a change in context (httpd_sys_rw_content_t).

Here is my security setup script:

```
# This file is intended to run as root
if [ "$EUID" -ne 0 ]
  then echo "Please run as root"
  exit
fi

# set this to your directory
LARAVELDIR=/var/www/html/cvprima
# just in case the log file does not exist yet
touch $LARAVELDIR/storage/logs/laravel.log
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_log_t $LARAVELDIR/storage/logs/laravel.log
chgrp www $LARAVELDIR/storage/logs $LARAVELDIR/storage/logs/*.log
chmod g+w $LARAVELDIR/storage/logs

# now for the ./storage/ directory
STORAGE=$LARAVELDIR/storage
for dir in $STORAGE/framework/cache $STORAGE/framework/sessions $STORAGE/framework/views $STORAGE/app/public $LARAVELDIR/bootstrap/cache ;do
  chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t $dir 2>/dev/null 1>&2
  # you _should_ actually never have .gitignore in these directories...
  chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t $dir/.gitignore  2>/dev/null 1>&2
  chgrp www $dir $dir/*  2>/dev/null 1>&2
  chmod -R g+w $dir $dir/*  2>/dev/null 1>&2
done
```

More things you can do (but be careful because these are recursive)

```
# all your files need to be httpd_sys_content_t (including the ./vendor/* directory tree)
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t $LARAVELDIR

# You either need files to be o+r, or chgrp www and g+r so that your webserver can access them.
chgrp -R www $LARAVELDIR
chmod -R g+r $LARAVELDIR
find $LARAVELDIR -type d | xargs chmod -R g+rx
```

Protect your .env file (make it -rw-r-----. 1 prima www)

```
chgrp www $LARAVELDIR/.env
chmod 640 $LARAVELDIR/.env
```

my user is called "prima", adjust accordingly.

ps: 
If you need to know more about SELinux, search for this on the web: "cameron selinux for mere mortals" there is a video presentation and a pdf.

PLEASE do not run with open permissions!